# photo recovery for Samsung A5 without using a computer

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, data-recovery

how do I recover my photo album  that I deleted  if I don't have a computer? I have a Samsung A5

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `data-recovery` tag to your question. You might wish starting with [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info), which mentions available methods and approaches. Then please come back here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) (when solved) – or let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck. Important details are also whether the device is rooted, and where that album was stored.

Comment: I think without PC it can't be done  ! I don't know might be there is a solution with someone. I probably can suggest you to download "Dumpster Android Data Recovery app" from play store, there is a slight chance that you got your files, if it is in recycle bin of play store, you really can recover it. Check this link : http://www.qdtricks.org/how-to-recover-deleted-files-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a while back, and I'm glad to say I know how to fix it :)

I have an A5 too, and I used this app to fix the problem: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defianttech.diskdigger
Diskdigger is specifically made for this purpose, and has helped me a lot in the past.
Hope you find this helpful :)